# Xamarin.Forms Relative Layout Xaml

Tags: xamarin, xaml, xamarin-forms

To tentando criar uma tela que tem uma imagem no final da screen e por cima dela fica os botoes de login, tipo essa aqui:
[image: tela que quero]

com o retangulo amarelo em baixo e os botoes por cima dela.
mas nao consigo fazer, veja o resultado:

[image: tela que fiz]

e aqui vai o codigo:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="vanhack.mobile.StartPageView"
         BackgroundImage="bg.png">
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Tentando Fazer um layout bonito!" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
        <RelativeLayout >
            <Button Text="Log In With e-mail" Command="{Binding EmailLoginCommand}"></Button>
            <Image Source="Rectangle2.png"  />
            <Image Source="linkedin.png"  />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Como ajeitar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A imagem está sobrepondo o botão, basta adicionar o botão após a imagem.

```
<RelativeLayout >
   <Image Source="Rectangle2.png"  />
   <Image Source="linkedin.png"  />
   <Button Text="Log In With e-mail" Command="{Binding EmailLoginCommand}"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> **Veja o resultado:**

[image: Captura tela]

Recomendo o uso de `Grid` caso queira posicionar o botão em um local específico da tela.
Cor do botão utilizado no exemplo:

```
<Button Text="Log In With e-mail" Command="{Binding EmailLoginCommand}" BackgroundColor="#F2C248"/>
```

Comment: Olá! obrigado por responder, viu que o triangulo amarelo perdeu tamanho?
queria que ficasse do msm tamanho. =x

Comment: @Biellx Eu não tenho as imagens originais que você utilizou, se deixar um link para elas aqui posso fazer outro teste. Vale lembrar também que é importante positivar e marcar a resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, não usa esse relative layout, tenta usar o grid que é muito melhor.

O grid tem um comportamento parecido com o table onde você controla a quantidade de linhas e colunas e consegue usar o span igual no html

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />  isso serve para ajustar a largura de acordo com o tamanho do campo
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />isso serve para preencher todo o espaço
      <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```